# Click function not working

Tags: vb.net

I have a small project that I'm stuck on.I'm trying to create an app to create Yahoo email accounts. The problem with the code is that the click action generates this error: "Looks like there was some trouble creating your account. Please take a moment to review your answers." 
But when I manually click in the webbrowser control it works fine to get to the next page.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim _maryFirst() As String
    Dim _maryLast() As String
    Dim _maryZip() As String
    Dim _mstrPass As String
    Private Sub btnSignup_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSignup.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://eu.edit.yahoo.com/registration")
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        _mstrPass = RandomString(10)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        Dim strLastname As String
        WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
        strLastname = _maryLast(CInt(Int((2323 * Rnd()))))
        With WebBrowser1.Document
            If .Url.AbsoluteUri = "https://na.edit.yahoo.com/registration?.pd=&intl=us&origIntl=&done=&src=&last=&partner=yahoo_default&domain=&yahooid=&lang=en-US" Then
                .GetElementById("firstname").SetAttribute("value", _maryFirst(CInt(Int((810 * Rnd())))))
                .GetElementById("secondname").SetAttribute("value", strLastname)
                .GetElementById("yahooid").SetAttribute("value", strLastname & CInt(Int((9999 * Rnd()) + 1001)))
                .GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", _mstrPass)
                .GetElementById("passwordconfirm").SetAttribute("value", _mstrPass)
                .GetElementById("mm").SetAttribute("value", CInt(Int((12 * Rnd()) + 1)))
                .GetElementById("dd").SetAttribute("value", CInt(Int((25 * Rnd()) + 1)))
                .GetElementById("yyyy").SetAttribute("value", CInt(Int(((1980 - 1950) * Rnd()) + 1950)))
                .GetElementById("gender").SetAttribute("value", "f")
                .GetElementById("postalcode").SetAttribute("value", _maryZip(CInt(Int(29469 * Rnd()))))
                .GetElementById("IAgreeBtn").InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _maryFirst = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath() & "\firstnames.txt")
        _maryLast = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath() & "\lastnames.txt")
        _maryZip = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath() & "\zip.txt")

    End Sub

    Private Shared Function RandomString(cb As Integer) As String

        Randomize()
        Dim rgch As String
        rgch = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        rgch = rgch & UCase(rgch) & "0123456789"
        RandomString = ""
        ' ReSharper disable NotAccessedVariable
        Dim i As Long
        ' ReSharper restore NotAccessedVariable
        For i = 1 To cb
            RandomString = RandomString & Mid$(rgch, Int(Rnd() * Len(rgch) + 1), 1)
        Next

    End Function

End Class
```

Commenting out

```
.GetElementById("IAgreeBtn").InvokeMember("click")
```

then run the program and click on the "create my account" button in the web browser control will complete the first page of the process. This tells me that there is an issue with the above line of code that somehow isn't working the same way as manually clicking the button.

Comment: Something tells me that the `IAgreeBtn` isn't the `input` element.

Comment: Please don't include the C# tag when the question is pure VB

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I just checked again `<input type="submit" name="IAgreeBtn" id="IAgreeBtn" value="Create my account" title="" border="0" aria-label="Create my account" aria-describedby="disclaimer" tabindex="1">`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code, it appears that the problem could be that the web browser control and the button code are operating against two different locales for yahoo: the web browser is using na and the button is using eu.

Comment: and how do i fix this issue?

Comment: Determine which region you intend to authenticate against and change both URLs to that region. In one, you have `https://na.`, which I am assuming is North America, and in the other you have `https://eu.` which I am assuming is Europe.